# Issue on stoping and starting aws Ec2 wordpress(centos 6.9) vm

Tags: linux, wordpress, amazon-web-services, centos, lamp

I have configured wordpress in a lamp setup in centos 6.9 server.

It's an aws ec2 instance. When i stop the vm and start it again database connectivity of wordpress is lost.How do i resolve this?

I tested by rebooting from inside vm. At that time everything is working fine. But not when i stop and start from aws dashbord.. any solution?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Provide details on the EC2 instance type and the type of storage attached (instance store volume, ebs, etc.). If you have created an EC2 instance with an instance store volume, then all changes are discarded when you stop the instance. Rebooting preserves data. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/InstanceStorage.html#instance-store-volumes

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be with your mysql service , after rebooting if you have not specified that it should run at start of server it would not run.

Also Make sure you have connection string as localhost and Elastic (Static) IP assigned to it.

If that is the case you can resolve it by adding the service to run every time instance start by this command:

```
sudo chkconfig mysqld on
```

Comment: No i had done all those things.I dont have a static ip.is it a issue?

Comment: Is the Db on RDS ?

Comment: db running on same instance.

Comment: Are you using IP in connection string or local host ?

Comment: local host..since i dont have static ip.when i assigned static ip its is working perfectly fine..

Comment: good to know problem got resolved , please mark answer as solution if it helped